# position: fixed with background image?

Tags: html, background, position

When I add the `<!DOCTYPE HTML>` on the page I am finding that I have to add `position: fixed;` into the CSS in order for the image to show up as the background on the "div" otherwise I get a blank, white background. Why does this require that position = fixed in this case?

```
 .background_image{
    position: fixed; <-----Why is this needed & Why doesn't static work?
    background: #000 url(../Images/Image.jpg) center center;
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
    min-height:100%;
    background-size: cover;
    overflow: hidden;
}
```

Here is the sample html. There is obviously other elements within the div and I am importing the css through a link in the header.

```
<body>
    <div class="background_image">
    </div>
</body>
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This happens, because `height: 100%` works in `position: fixed`. When you remove this position, it doesn't take this `height`. So, there is another way to do this. You can use `vh` units. Remove position `fixed`, and add this background this `css`:

```
 .background_image{
  height: 100vh;
  background: #000 url(../Images/Image.jpg) center center;
  width: 100%;
  min-height:100%;
  background-size: cover;
  overflow: hidden;
  }
```

Comment: Thanks...this worked great. What is considered the proper way to set the background here? Fixed or Static?

Comment: @TsTeaTime, in this case leave it static. Background attachment fixed, is used to achieve the paralx effect.

Answer (score 1):

The  mean html so the page must follow the HTML 5 rule

> FROM MDN Css doc
>
> The position CSS property chooses alternative rules for positioning
>   elements, designed to be useful for scripted animation effects.
>
> **Values**
>
> **static**
>
> This keyword lets the element use the normal behavior, that is it is
>   laid out in its current position in the flow.  The top, right, bottom,
>   left and z-index properties do not apply.
>
> **relative**
>
> This keyword lays out all elements as though the element were not
>   positioned, and then adjust the element's position, without changing
>   layout (and thus leaving a gap for the element where it would have
>   been had it not been positioned). The effect of position:relative on
>   table-*-group, table-row, table-column, table-cell, and table-caption
>   elements is undefined.
>
> **absolute**
>
> Do not leave space for the element. Instead, position it at a
>   specified position relative to its closest positioned ancestor if any,
>   or otherwise relative to the initial containing block. Absolutely
>   positioned boxes can have margins, and they do not collapse with any
>   other margins.
>
> **fixed**
>
> Do not leave space for the element. Instead, position it at a
>   specified position relative to the screen's viewport and don't move it
>   when scrolled. When printing, position it at that fixed position on
>   every page. This value always create a new stacking context. When an
>   ancestor has the transform property set to something different than
>   none then this ancestor is used as container instead of the viewport

Answer (score 0):

You should use background-attachment property with images.

background-attachment can have one out of two values.
background-attachment: fixed|scroll;

position property is used to position html elements like div, p,etc.. So you can't use it with images.

You'll find this link useful

http://www.w3schools.com/cssref/pr_background-attachment.asp